# height: 100% on inner div in semantic UI column broken in Safari

Tags: css, safari, semantic-ui

I'm attempting to use Semantic UI to create a row of equal height columns separated by a gutter. My solution works in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari (I haven't tested IE yet). Safari dev tools show that each column has an equal height as expected however creating an `.inner` div and setting the height to 100% has no effect on the height of `.inner`.

I believe I need the `.inner` div in order for each block to have a background colour separated by a gutter.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/fb32hn0y/3/) a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem. For me it renders like this in Chrome:

[image: Correctly rendered in Chrome]

and like this in Safari:

[image: Incorrectly rendered in Safari]

I'm not sure if this is a bug in WebKit (or even blink/gecko!), I found a [similar bug in webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559) but it's marked as fixed/resolved.

If there's nothing wrong with my approach to this can someone suggest a workaround? Preferably without patching with JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Could you please use `display:table;` it will work.

```css
.inner {
  height:  100%
}
body {
  font-family: "helvetica";
  background: white;
}
#column-1 {
  background: #e3e0cf;
}
#column-2 {
  background: #9fa8a3;
}
.equal { display:table; }
.column { display:table-cell; }
```

```html
<div class="ui stackable equal height grid">
  <div class="six wide column" id="column-1">

    <h1>Column 1</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="six wide column" id="column-2">

    <h1>Column 2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this doesn't work as a solution because by getting rid of the `.inner` div you lose the whitespace between the elements http://i.imgur.com/V6v0AXM.png if I add `.inner` back in then the same bug persists even with `display: table;`

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue in Safari indeed. A workaround for this is to define a height property on **.ui.grid .column** and set your **div.inner** height to 'inherit'. Below is a css code that works in Safari browser:

```
div.inner{
    height:inherit;
    background-color:gold;
}

.ui.grid .column{
    height:25vh;
}
```

Screenshot: [image]